# Get the last and the next to last row per id from a dataset in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-07'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-07')
```

And I want to group by id and get the last and the next-to-last date value (`the_debt_paid`) from a table. That means that is ordered in desc by `the_debt_paid`.

This is the expected output:

```
the_debt_id    the_debt_paid     the_debt_due
LMUS01         2019-07-01        2019-07-02
LMUS01         2019-06-03        2019-06-02
LMUS02         2019-06-07        2019-06-07
LMUS02         2019-05-03        2019-05-07
```

I think there's a function like lead or lag, but not so sure how to use it:

```
SELECT *, LAG(the_debt_paid) 
OVER (PARTITION BY the_debt_id ORDER BY the_debt_paid DESC) 
FROM my_table
```

But I got stuck. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below - using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
SELECT *, row_number()
OVER (PARTITION BY the_debt_id ORDER BY the_debt_paid DESC) as rn
FROM my_table
)A where rn<=2
```

Comment: Hello @Fahmi, just a question, there's an `A` next to the close parenthesis. It is like an alias?

Comment: @Manu, yes when you write a subquery you need to give it a name, so A is an alias for the subquery

Comment: Hello @Fahmi, I run your solution on a fiddle `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b83c0d82fc570d7647bd2d27d1412dd9` but it returns me an error saying that `rn` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Manu, I've updated it - you can check now - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=27eff5e9e53868b1e08218d077c099e7

Comment: Great @Fahmi, it needed an alias with the name `rn`. Thank you very much, have a great day.